# Python SQL database to sparse matrix using pickles

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sparse-matrix

I'd like to import some large data to python. I've tries using ordinary dataframes, but since I have to perform some resource consuming operations, I constantly run into Memory Errors.

My new Approach is to download the data in pickles from the SQL database and load it to python as sparse Matrices. For this I wrote two functions, but it doesn't work.

Please excuse my code, I'm quite new to python. I'll be glad to receive any piece of advice. Thank you!

```
    def DatabaseToFile(query, local_filename):
        filename = local_filename + '.obj'
        import pickle
        import pyodbc

        li_log = list()
        pickle_filehandler = open(filename, 'wb') # write binary mode
        pickle.dump(li_log, pickle_filehandler)

        connection = pyodbc.connect(
                r"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                r"Server=my_server;"
                r"Database=my_database;"
                r"uid=my_user;"
                r"pwd=my_password;"
                )
        with connection as session:
            for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, session, chunksize=50000):
                pickle.dump(chunk, pickle_filehandler)
        session.close()
        pickle_filehandler.close()
        return li_log


    def FileToMatrix(local_filename):
        import pickle
        filename = local_filename + '.obj'
        pickle_filehandler = open(filename, 'rb') # read binary mode
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        while True:
            try:
                chunk = pickle.load(pickle_filehandler)
                df = df.append(chunk, ignore_index=True)
            except:
                break
        sdf = df.to_sparse()    
        pickle_filehandler.close()
        return sdf
```

Comment: Why first to a pickle and directly converting the chunks to a sparse dataframe? :)

Comment: You mean just skip the step of saving the data to a local file?

Comment: Yes :) Just read and append each chunk to a sparse dataframe.